# Monitoring file for changes and immediately take action on change

Tags: monitoring, cron, scheduled-task, task-scheduler, background-process

How can I *constantly* monitor (small) file for changes?

Eg. when file is updated (action from web application), a script is executed (if not already running).

Right now, I do it every minute using cron, but this has delay up to one minute. I'd like to take the action immediately after the file is changed.

Maybe I need to write some low level process running in the background, once the server is started?

The reason I want to do it is to separate web application from root actions (performed on demand, once when file is updated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

incrond (inotify cron daemon) behaves like cron but uses inotify as the triggering mechanism. [This guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/) has some pretty comprehensive examples.

An example incron entry for the case you described might be:

```
/path/to/file IN_CLOSE_WRITE /path/to/your_script
```

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely, except the fact I need an unique instance of `/your_script` to be running (ie. wait for the previous instance to finish)

Comment: @takeshin A cheap thing would be modify the script to sleep for a few seconds while an instance of itself already exists. Something like this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1402516&p=8800984#post8800984

Comment: The solution from your link works ok, thanks (but it assumes the .pid file exists and it's not empty)

Answer (score 1):

incron is the software you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Linux, as I assume you are, then you can rely on Linux `inotify` mechanism that notifies user-space processes when files change.

[LSyncd](https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) is one program built around that feature, which you can configure to execute arbitrary commands when files change.